# Routing with optional parameters and regex

Tags: php, regex, laravel, routes

I will route this url with single route:

- www.web.com/some.xml
- www.web.com/some1.xml
- www.web.com/some2.xml

I have tried with the following code, url **www.web.com/some1.xml, some2.xml, etc is found**, but url **www.web.com/some.xml** always **not found**.

```
Route::get('/{postTypeSlug}{index?}{xml?}', [
    'as' => 'root_sitemap_post_detail',
    'uses' => 'SingledomainSitemapController@sitemapPostDetail'
    ])->where('postTypeSlug', "(info-sehat|rubrik)\B")->where('index', "([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)\b");
```

I expect the url www.web.com/some.xml and some1.xml, some2.xml, etc can be found.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but you probably want to use `*` instead of **+**.

```
 a* 0 or more
 a+ 1 or more
 a? 0 or 1
```

And for `[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]+` You can probably just use `[1-9]*|[1-9][0-9]*`